# Descending not working in query, but it should work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a scoreboard for my internship, for the games we play in the break. I have a really big query to get the results of all games and count the total of wins by players.

```
SELECT winner, SUM(total) AS total 
FROM (SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total 
      FROM billiard_games g 
      INNER JOIN players p1 
          ON p1.id = g.player_1 
      INNER JOIN players p2 
          ON p2.id = g.player_2 
      LEFT JOIN billiard_winners w 
          ON w.id = g.id 
      LEFT JOIN players pw 
          ON pw.id = w.winner 
      WHERE winner IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY winner 

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total 
      FROM dart_games g 
      INNER JOIN players p1 
          ON p1.id = g.player_1 
      INNER JOIN players p2 
          ON p2.id = g.player_2 
      LEFT JOIN dart_winners w 
          ON w.id = g.id 
      LEFT JOIN players pw 
          ON pw.id = w.winner 
      GROUP BY winner 

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total 
      FROM fifa_games g 
      INNER JOIN players p1 
          ON p1.id = g.player_1 
      INNER JOIN players p2 
          ON p2.id = g.player_2 
      LEFT JOIN fifa_winners w 
          ON w.id = g.id 
      LEFT JOIN players pw 
          ON pw.id = w.winner 
      WHERE winner IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY winner ) A 
WHERE winner IS NOT NULL 
group by winner DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Output:

```
Player_1 | 5
Player_2 | 1
Player_3 | 3
```

That's not the right order. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I wrote the code in php, but had to add more tags to it.

Comment: i didnt find any ORDER BY DESC in your query

Comment: You're missing an `ORDER BY`...? `GROUP BY`...`DESC` is not really a thing.

Comment: Some line-breaks would make the query much easier to read.

Comment: FYI - I removed the PHP tag since the question is 100% about SQL.

Comment: `ORDER BY total DESC` is the key here.

Comment: I am such a derp, I accidentially removed the order by winner desc.. THanks guys.

Comment: Why are you not having order by DESC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last part should be

```
WHERE winner IS NOT NULL group by winner order by total DESC LIMIT 5
```

Because you just missed the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Order by winner or total ?

Comment: i think `ORDER BY total DESC` is the key here. but sorry to say that, dont know about the down voter. my vote for u.

Comment: sorry, my bad. *Edited*